# Ordering of Records in Stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Here are some of the queries I have :

I have two different streams `stream1` and `stream2` in which the elements are in order.

1) Now when I do `keyBy` on each of these streams, will the order be maintained? (Since every group here will be sent to one task manager only ) 
My understanding is that the records will be in order for a group, correct me here.

2) After the `keyBy` on both of the streams I am doing co-group to get the matching and non-matching records. Will the order be maintained here also?, since this also works on `KeyedStream`. 
I am using `EventTime`, and `AscendingTimestampExtractor` for generating `timestamp` and `watermark`.

3) Now I want to perform the sequence check on the `matching_nonMatchingStream` I get from 2) using map/flatmap. 
Do I need to again perform the `keyBy` here , or if I keep in chain will the `matching_nonMatchingStream` run in same `TaskManager`? 
My understanding here is that the chain will work here, correct me , getting confused.

4) `slotSharingGroup` - can you please describe more about this 
according to the doc : Sets the slot sharing group of this operation. Parallel instances of operations that are in the same slot sharing group will be co-located in the same `TaskManager` slot, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes and no. Flink uses so-called [Watermarks](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/event_time.html#event-time-and-watermarks) to track the ordering. This ensures that records can be assigned to the correct windows and windows are not closed until all data is available. However, a strict order is not guaranteed per group (because of [parallel incoming data](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/event_time.html#watermarks-in-parallel-streams)). Between groups, there is no ordering guarantee at all.

2) Basically same answer as for (1).

3) You do not need to use `keyBy` again. The `map`/`flatMap` will be chained by default.

4) See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/internals/general_arch.html#the-processes

Comment: Flink does not provide any sort operation. You will need to write UDF code for this.

Comment: `@matthias-j-sax` : 1) So if I want to maintain the strict order per group, I will have to perform the sort operation, right ?

2) So if the order is not guaranteed , using AscendingTimestampExtractor does not make sense

3) Now, the watermarks gets emitted when it is larger than the previous one, so does this mean I have to maintain current and  prevTimestamp and check in getCurrentWaterMark() method 
`if(currentTimestamp > prevTimestamp)`

Comment: You can still use `AscendingTimestampExtractor` -- which extractor you use, depends on your use case semantics and is independent from ordering guarantees. If you want to do the sorting, you need to buffer all tuples between to watermarks. When you receive the second watermark, you can sort all buffered tuples and emit in the correct order. Finally, you empty your buffer and start from scratch for the next watermark-watermark interval. Watermarks guarantee that there will be no more late arriving data with respect to the current watermark. Thus, sorting the buffer will give the correct result.

Comment: I am not clear exactly where should I buffer my elements, are you trying to say buffer the elements in the `getCurrentTimestamp()` and sort the elements in `getCurrentWatermark()` (I am confused here)

_When you receive the second watermark, you can sort all buffered tuples and emit in the correct order_ - did not get this, my understanding is that we will sort the elements in `getCurrentWatermark` but where exactly we emit the results ?

Comment: Can we discuss this via email -- it's getting complicated... mjsax@apache.org (and comment field is limited in size). And this is not related to your original question anymore.

Answer (score 5):

## Concerning Ordering Guarantees

This page gives a good overview and explanation, also of ordering guarantees: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/concepts/concepts.html#parallel-dataflows

**The Gist is:**

Order is maintained **within each parallel stream partition**. For an explanation of stream partitions, see here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/concepts/concepts.html#parallel-dataflows

For operations like "keyBy()" or "rebalance()" that change the partitioning, the order is maintained per pair of source and target stream partition, meaning per pair of sending and receiving operator.

As Matthias mentioned, if a group (defined by a key, running on one receiving target operator) gets elements from multiple senders, there is no well defined strict ordering of elements. Using concepts like event time, you can impose a meaningful ordering based on the data (the attached timestamps).

Comment: yes I am using event time for windowing, but unable to understand where do I sort the elements (We have actually done the sorting in apply method for one use-case where the data was out of order)

Now considering I am able to sort the records, so according to the document, if I just apply one-one streams all the downstream operators will receive the elements in order.

Only if I do keyBy or rebalance or other operator, the ordering will have effect, right ?