# Flink assurance of ordered streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From my little experience with Flink I have noticed that even If we have events arriving at the order they should be arriving after partitioning the order is lost. This is discussed here:
[Ordering of Records in Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354713/ordering-of-records-in-stream)

So I have 3 questions that extend the question mentioned above:

1. The reason the order is lost after the keyBy function is still unclear to me. Why does that happen?
2. Is there a way to ensure the order of the events even after the partitioning?
3. If we do not create KeyedStreams, is the order of the events guaranteed per parallel operator?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might have been some misunderstanding here. I'll try to reclarify some things here:

The ordering of elements will be retained for elements emitted from the same operator with the same key. However, on the receiving side after the partitioning, there isn't any strict ordering if you account for all the records with the same key that it receives, simply because ordering is guaranteed for per-parallel operator.

Comment: I am not taking into account all the records in question 1. I am talking about records with the same key. Even if events arrive in order, after the partitioning, order per key is lost (even if they do arrive in order).